# Installing local dependency with pip install

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I am using the Setuptools build backend for a `pyproject.toml`-based project.

I have this project structure:

```
- project_root
    - dependency_lib
        - pyproject.toml
        - * other files *
    - src
        - package_name
            - __init__.py
            * different .py files *
    - README.md
    - pyproject.toml
```

Now I want to install my local package in `src/package_name` using `pip install .` or `pip install -e .` In `pyproject.toml`,  I have different dependencies which are working fine. However, the local package also depends on `dependency_lib`, which is a separate package with its own `pyproject.toml`, and which is added as a git submodule. I want `dependency_lib` to be installed automatically when I use `pip install .`.

Can I do this by specifying dependencies in `pyproject.toml`? If so, how?

I saw a suggestion to add the dependency as `"dependency_lib@ file:///{$PROJECT_ROOT}/dependency_lib"`, but this fails due to unknown `$PROJECT_ROOT`. Is there a way to get the path automatically, based on the location of `pyproject.toml`? I would prefer not to add it manually to my environment variables.

Alternately, is there a better way to structure the project (e.g. putting `dependency_lib` somewhere else) so that this works more simply?

Comment: `python -m pip install --editable . --editable ./dependency_lib` -- Or you can craft a `requirements.txt` file that simplifies it for you. -- No you can't have relative path dependencies in the packaging metadata directly. -- You could potentially migrate to a "development workflow tool" like hatch, pdm, poetry, and so on. Not sure exactly which ones have support for this and how exactly this is done. Some might allow to keep setuptools as build backend. This is something you should investigate for yourself, based on what your needs and wants are.

Comment: @sinoroc that is a shame that relative paths are not allowed... I am aware of poetry and used to use it, but now I am sadly limited to setuptools by factors not depending on me. I guess I will use `python -m pip install --editable . --editable ./dependency_lib`, you can put it as a separate answer if you want it accepted.

Comment: There is a good reasoning why (relative) paths are not allowed in the package metadata: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/ ; but they are allowed in plenty other places, `requirements.txt` is one of them. -- Note that the `--editable` flags in that pip command are optional, depends if editable installations are needed or not.

Comment: "but it fails due to unknown $PROJECT_ROOT (is there way to get it automatically from the location of pyproject.toml? I would not like to add it manually to environment variables)." - the syntax there explicitly means to use the value of such an environment variable. But from what I understood in the specification (PEP 508), I don't think that works in pyproject.toml anyway.

Comment: @sinoroc I think there's plenty between your two comments to constitute a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, I was hoping there is some way to automatically set the variable, but I realized there is none. I went with @sinoroc's proposition to just install both separately in a `pip install` command. As I mentioned, I used poetry before, so was a bit hoping there is some way to make it work also with setuptools, but I guess not.

Comment: As an aside, if you prefer to discuss the matter on an actual discussion forum (this is not one), you could certainly do worse than https://discuss.python.org/ .